# Can students use Turnitin to view papers submitted by other students in the class?

Tags: plagiarism

Does the Turnitin Similarity Report show students snippets from papers submitted by other students in the same class?

For example, say John submits his paper a few days before the due date. Then Tim uploads his own paper and reviews his Similarity Report. Say Tim's paper shows a high similarity with something John wrote. Can Tim then click on the match and read parts of John's paper?

Comment: Only the parts which are common.